# Action from extbase controller doesn't lead to correct view

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have two plugins in my extbase extension.

`Pi1` is named `Items` with the actions `list` and `show`.

`Pi2` is named `Exclusive` and contains the action `listexclusive`

`listexclusive` returns all Items which are tagged as exclusive. But i want a link on each item to the `show` action of `Pi1`.

In my view i did this with:

```
//exclusive items (Listexclusive.html)
<f:for each="{items}" as="item">

  <f:link.action pluginName="Pi1" controller="Item" action="show" arguments="{item : item}">
  <p>{item.title} // {item.price}<p>
  </f:link.action>

</f:for>
```

When i click on an item from the above rendered view i land on the same page **instead** on the detail-view from the show-action. The url looks like

```
http://my.local.dev/index.php?id=1333&tx_items_pi1%5Bitem%5D=229&tx_items_pi1%5Baction%5D=show&tx_items_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Item&cHash=f2bfb64cc56fe7f3a9652e803be7a461
```

**How can i get a detail-view (show-action) when i click on the links (exclusive items) from the above rendered view?**

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need set the page uid of the detail page to get a link to this page. TYPO3 does not know where you have inserted the plugin with the detail view. If `pageUid` is not set, the link links to the same page.

```html
<f:link.action pageUid="27836" pluginName="Pi1" controller="Item" action="show" arguments="{item : item}">
    <p>{item.title} // {item.price}<p>
</f:link.action>
```

You should set the UID of the detail view page in the settings section in the setup.txt of your extension. If done, you can use for example `{settings.detailPageUid}` in your templates.

Comment: so i should better add a flexform for this setting right?

Comment: Well, if you have multiple detail view pages, then yes. But if not, simply set ``plugin.tx_items.settings.detailPageUid = xyz`` via TypoScript and you are able to use the setting globally in your extension.

Comment: Thank you very much Merec!! you made my day.